# How do I make this rig's poses able to be x-axis mirrored

Tags: rigging

I don't understand how to make the rig's poses mirrored on this rig. I tried naming each bone the _L and _R, and it still didn't work. Can someone help me out?

Blender File: https://www.mediafire.com/file/qx4eosdi9o6yv0f/Sora_KH2.blend/file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work for the moment because:

- Your bones need to have the same name on both side...
- They need a different suffix: _L or .L for the left bones, _R or .R for the right bones

Here is what a *Copy* and *Paste Pose Flipped* gives with the feet controllers, once I've renamed them. It can't work with the current names:

[image]

Comment: I tried this before and it didn’t work. But I’ll try again. Do I need to save the file for this to work?

Comment: no you don't need to save. Well I've tried with your file and it works so I think it will fix your problem

Comment: Ok, thank you...

Comment: Are you on 2.8 and up?

Comment: yes, it should work with all the versions

Comment: It's still not working for me. Can I see your file?

Comment: I've just changed the feet controllers and named it control_L and control_R: https://pasteall.org/blend/f5dabea40e3f41889b3ab0e352176735

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but it looks like its not working for you either.

Comment: what do you mean? actually in the file I've shared, I've just renamed the feet controllers and it works fine, if you move these 2 bones, copy then flip-paste, it will mirror the pose, is it not what you want?

Comment: Oh, I meant for the upper half it still bugs out. But you were right about the legs.

Comment: what part? I may miss something but I can't see any IK for the arm. Also make sure that you create the same name with this kind of suffixes: _L, _R or .L, .R

Comment: Are you saying this technique only works on IK’s? I guess it does make sense.

Comment: no it works on every bones but most of the times the ones you move are the IK controllers

Comment: Gotcha. Well thanks.